Correct way of calling processing algorithm multiple times with different parameters
I have a processing algorithm that loads layers, applies styling, and adds to the project. I would like to call the processing algorithm simultaneously with different parameters (batch loading).
I have found https://www.opengis.ch/2018/06/22/threads-in-pyqgis3/
but it has been applied only for one execution. I tried to reproduce
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        ### steps that not important
        alg = QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithmById(X)
        for layer in layers:
            # data = load_layer(layer)
            # results.update(data)

            task = QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask(alg, layer_params[layer], context, feedback)

            task.executed.connect(partial(self.task_finished, context))
            QgsApplication.taskManager().addTask(task)
def task_finished(self, context, successful, results):
    if not successful:
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Task finished unsucessfully',
                                 'My processing tasks',
                                 Qgis.Warning)
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(results,
                             'My processing tasks',
                             Qgis.Info)
    print(f'errs ss {results}')

    output_layer = context.getMapLayer(results['OUTPUT'])

    # because getMapLayer doesn't transfer ownership the layer will be
    # deleted when context goes out of scope and you'll get a crash.
    # takeResultLayer transfers ownership so it's then safe to add it to the
    # project and give the project ownership.
    if output_layer.isValid():
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(
            context.takeResultLayer(output_layer.id()))

My processing uses QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface and postProcessAlgorithm, which I believe makes it consistent to work with projects separately. I have tried loading in sequence and it is working. Are there any examples? My attempts leading to crashes of QGIS...

@codebard Hi, I have seen your replies regarding the QgsTask, can you have a look at mine pls?
